Instances of Keycloak installed on AWS ECS not synced
I have installed on ECS keycloak with 2 containers. The infinispan config has also been updated from the default -1 to 30000(30 seconds). But when a user or realm is created, it takes a while to reflect for other admin users. What are the possible issues?

Are you using the ec2 stack configuration as described here? https://www.keycloak.org/server/caching You need to edit your question to show your entire configuration.

The issue was with AWS security group blocking communication between containers on the port jgroup utilizes, i.e. 7800
